# How to perform Shanken (1992) correction for errors-in-variables issue?

Tags: asset-pricing, fama-french

I have two questions pertaining to the Shanken correction:

1. The formula of Shanken correction shown in the Cochrane (2001) Asset Pricing book is as follow:

$$\sigma^2(\hat{\lambda}_{OLS})=1/T[(\beta^{'}\beta)^{-1}\beta^{'}\Sigma\beta(\beta^{'}\beta)^{-1}(1+\lambda^{'}\Sigma_{f}^{-1}\lambda)+\Sigma_{f}]$$

I think I did not understand the formula correctly as I think the multiplicative term will result in a scalar, whereas the additive term will be in matrix form given that $\Sigma_{f}$ is the variance-covariance matrix of factors. So, it's impossible to add a scalar and a matrix, right? So, I might misunderstand it. I have looked through some lecture examples online, most of them dealing with a single factor (i.e. CAPM beta), hence the $\Sigma_{f}$ is simply the variance of the market excess returns. But I'm wondering how am I going to compute this correction if I have multiple factors (e.g. Fama-French three-factor model)? Do I need to compute the variance-covariance matrix of all factors or only employ the variance of a relevant factor in calculating the adjusted standard error?

2. The formula stated in Shanken (1992) also seemed to be slightly different to me:

$$(1+c)[\hat{W}-\hat{\Sigma}_{F}]+\hat{\Sigma_{F}}$$

I'm wondering why this formula has an additional term, $\hat{\Sigma}_{F}$, to be subtracted from the sample covariance matrix, $\hat{W}$, as compared to the formula above.

Answer (score 1):

### Question 1

If there are $k=1$ factors (i.e. a single factor):

1. $\beta$ is a vector (a single-column matrix),
2. $(\beta^{'}\beta)^{-1}\beta^{'}\Sigma\beta(\beta^{'}\beta)^{-1}$ is a scalar,
3. $\lambda^{'}\Sigma_{f}^{-1}\lambda$ is a scalar and thus
4. $(\beta^{'}\beta)^{-1}\beta^{'}\Sigma\beta(\beta^{'}\beta)^{-1}(1+\lambda^{'}\Sigma_{f}^{-1}\lambda)$ is a **scalar**, matching
5. $\Sigma_{f}$ that is a **scalar**.

If there are $k>1$ factors:

1. $\beta$ is a $k$-column matrix,
2. $(\beta^{'}\beta)^{-1}\beta^{'}\Sigma\beta(\beta^{'}\beta)^{-1}$ is a matrix
3. $\lambda^{'}\Sigma_{f}^{-1}\lambda$ is a scalar and thus
4. $(\beta^{'}\beta)^{-1}\beta^{'}\Sigma\beta(\beta^{'}\beta)^{-1}(1+\lambda^{'}\Sigma_{f}^{-1}\lambda)$ is a **matrix**, matching
5. $\Sigma_{f}$ that is a **matrix**.

The dimensions seem to match in both cases.

### Question 2

See the summary of Shanken (1992) laid out nicely in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/412112/implementation-of-shanken-1992-adjustement-for-fama-macbeth-asset-pricing-test/441108#441108) on Cross Validated. It seems Cochrane's (2005) treatment omits some details, and the equation you give is not considered explicitly by Cochrane.